# Get the index that caused an IndexError exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to get the index that caused an `IndexError` exception?

**Sample code :**

```
arr = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
try:  
   print arr[10] # This will cause IndexError
except IndexError as e:
    print e.args # Can I get which index (in this case 10) caused the exception?
```

Comment: You could manually check against length of the list as the first IndexError would be caused at that point.

Comment: @sagarchalise, true, but it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only manually; for example:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
try:
    try_index = 42
    print(arr[try_index])
except IndexError:
    print 'Index', try_index, 'caused an IndexError'
```

Comment: I guess this is the simplest

Comment: Though this wont be useful when you are accessing 20 pre-decided indices of a list, in which case you need to update the try_index every time before you access the index.  As in print arr[0]; print arr[21]; print arr[15] etc

Comment: Well in that case you could always write a function that handles the exception, so that you can simply do `my_print(arr, 0); my_print(arr, 21); my_print(arr, 15);`

Answer (score 6):

There's no direct way, because unlike `KeyError`, `IndexError` doesn't provide this information (yet). You can subclass the built-in `list` to raise `IndexError` with arguments you want:

```
class vist(list): # Verbose list
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            v = super().__getitem__(item) # Preserve default behavior
        except IndexError as e:
            raise IndexError(item, *e.args) # Construct IndexError with arguments

        return v

arr = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6] # list
arr = vist(arr) # vist

try:
    arr[10]
except IndexError as e:
    print(e.args) # (10, 'list index out of range')
```

Actually, you don't even need to convert it back to normal `list`.

Comment: Just wondering but does `IndexError` provide this info in Python3 or does it still not do that?

Answer (score 4):

Except for manually keeping track of the index you accessed, I don't believe so, at least not in 2.7. Unless I am misreading the proposal, [there is a proposal for this in 3.5](http://bugs.python.org/issue18162).